# Blazor webassembly hosted software architecture

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, architecture, blazor-webassembly, software-design

I'm working on a Blazor webassembly project with asp.net core hosted it's in .net core 6.0
so the solution's folder architecture is

```
.
├── KM.sln
├── Client
│   ├── KM.Client.csproj
│   ├── App.razor
│   ├── _Imports.razor
│   ├── Pages (razor pages)
│   ├── Program.cs
│   ├── Properties
│   ├── Services (here happens all the calls for the API endpoints)
│   ├── Shared (razor components)
│   └── wwwroot
├── Server
│   ├── KM.Server.csproj
│   ├── Controllers (Here we use the repository classes)
│   ├── Data (DbContext)
│   ├── Entities
│   ├── Program.cs
│   ├── Properties
│   └── Repositories (Here is the server logic)
└── Shared
    ├── KM.Shared.csproj
    └── Dtos (Data Transfer Objects)
```

i want to know if this diagram can be named **software architecture**

[image: Software architecture]

I'm sure that the architecture is not MVC and neither MVVM so it's not clear what to call it so i though it can be layer architecture where the presentation layer is the Blazor webassembly app and the application layer is the asp.net core web api and there would be another shared layer for DTOs

i found no clear explanation in microsoft documentation so i did that diagram from scratch and i wanted to share it to know what you think

Comment: You can use this layering to understand, and there is nothing wrong with its execution logic. But what you need to know is that it is actually a separate front-end and back-end projects.